# Is $\mathbb{A}^{1}$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^{1}-\{0\}$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

Let's work over an algebraically closed field $k$. Consider the affine line $\mathbb{A}^{1}$ over $k$, equipped with the classical Zariski topology, i.e. the closed subsets of $\mathbb{A}^{1}$ are precisely $\emptyset$, finite subsets of $\mathbb{A}^{1}$, and $\mathbb{A}^{1}$ itself. In particular, $\mathbb{A}^{1}-\{0\}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{A}^{1}$ (and so can be equipped with the subspace topology). My question is:

> Is $\mathbb{A}^1$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^{1}-\{0\}$?

It is easy to see that $\mathbb{A}^1$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^{1}-\{0\}$ in the sense of varieties, because the ring of regular functions on these varieties are $k[x]$ and $k[x, 1/x]$, respectively. (Those two rings are not isomorphic). But I have no idea how one can show the existence/nonexistence of homeomorphism between these topological spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $k$ is algebraically closed, it is infinite. Thus, we can find a bijection between $\mathbb A^1$ and $\mathbb A^1 - \{0\}$. This bijection is automatically a homeomorphism since both spaces have the cofinite topology.